# iostream header vs iostream class

Tags: c++, iostream

If there is a file foo.cpp, then it usually has an associated header file foo.h with all the declarations for the functions defined in foo.cpp. That way all other files which make use of functions in the foo.cpp can just include the foo.h file and use them. Thats my simple understanding of header files.

---

However, I don't see such a relation between the iostream header file and the iostream class. The iostream header file only declares a few extern variables but none of them seem to have have anything to do with the iostream class directly. The iostream class also doesn't seem to declare any new functions. Why do we then have the iostream class and the iostream header files? Apologies if I sound confused, but this stuff really confuses me.

Comment: They are admittedly badly chosen names, mostly due to history. `iostream` isn't even a class, but a typedef for a class template. In the new C++11 standard, you will at least get guaranteed access to `iostream` by including <iostream>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between headers and classes isn't necessarily one-to-one; that's just a rule of thumb often taught to novice programmers. In fact, the C++ language standard does not specify any direct relation between classes, implementation files (*translation units*), and headers at all and the standard library often deviates from this rule.

`std::iostream` is a typedef for the template class `std::basic_iostream` (specifically, for `basic_iostream<char>`). On my platform, `<iostream>` includes `<istream>` which defines `basic_iostream`, as well as `<iosfwd>` which contains the `typedef`.

Comment: I might add that, according to the C++ standard, `<iostream>` is not even required to correspond to a file at all.  In any case, large libraries often expose "aggregate headers" which are guaranteed to make a subset of the library's symbols available to the source file with the `#include` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are a special case and you get into trouble if you declare a templated class or function and define it in another file. Since C++ compilers can only compile instantiations of templated elements (like `std::vector<int>`) and not their generic versions (that would be `std::vector<T>`), it needs to have the generic version available wherever an instantiation is made. Therefore, the implementation of a generic class is generally in its header file.